# I want to add number of days to particular date using javascript only

Tags: javascript

I want to add number of days to particular date using javascript only
example:

```
textbox1.text=10-04-2013
textbox2.text=30

textbox3.text=10-05-2013
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Please do a google and stackoverflow search before posting a question... posting a same question again and again does not help the community.

Comment: @AurA - if you find a perfect dupe, hit the close button and paste the duplicate URL in. No need to do anything else!

Comment: @Jamiec I already know and did that...

Comment: @AurA - really? Something's not working then because I did, and I only see 1 close vote (my own!) Weird.

Comment: @Jamiec I flagged it as duplicate.. I cannot close a question it requires 3000  reputation point :( http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
var yourDate= new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6;
someDate.setDate(yourDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```